# Error - "Object DOMDocument should be created" keeps appearing. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, blocks

I created a custom module, that was throwing back errors. So I disabled and removed it from the app/code dir.

Then I cleared `pub/static`, `var/generation`, `var/cache`, `var/view_processed`

But I still kept getting an error that the Block name of the removed module doesn't exist.

I tried redeploying the static files, reindexing and setup:upgrade in the hope that would fix it, but no luck.

So I ended up removing all the files and reverting to a back up from 4 days earlier.

But the error still shows up in my system.log?

```
main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Vendor\ProductSlider\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductSlider [] []
```

Comment: Block from removed Module can be embed in cms page, static block, etc...

Comment: thx for the hint to check system.log

Answer (score 4):

To remove extension completely from Magento, you need to following things.

1. Remove extension folder from app/code.
2. Remove extension entry from config.php file avilable at app/etc folder of magento.
3. Remove extension entry from "setup_module" table from database.
4. Remove extensin block which you put either in CMS page or CMS block.

Now run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```